# How to open a Swift App from same screen after phone settings configurations

Tags: ios, swift, settings

Need a quick help.

Though I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution for this. I need to use the camera in my iOS app and the case, when I need to visit phone settings to enable the camera permission, the iOS application is not opening from same view-controller where the permission was asked.

I read somewhere it will start from AppDelegate.swift if camera permission toggles. Is it true or we have any way to reach to the view-controller where permission asked.

Thanks for the help.